# Compiling Error with C++ and namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, forward-declaration

Here's the whole code getting the errors:

**Engine.h**

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include "DXManager.h"

namespace XEngine
{
    class Engine
    {
    };
}

#endif
```

**DXManager.h**

```
#ifndef DX_MANAGER_H
#define DX_MANAGER_H



namespace XEngine
{
    class Engine; // forward declaration

    class DXManager
    {
    public:
        void run(Engine *engine);
    };
}

#endif
```

**DXManager.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Engine.h"
#include "DXManager.h"

using namespace XEngine;

void DXManager::run(Engine *engine)
{
    std::cout<<"DXManager::run"<<std::endl;
}
```

With these 30 lines of code, I'm getting 20 errors like:

```
'XEngine' : a namespace with this name does not exist
'XEngine' : a symbol with this name already exists and therefore this name cannot be used as a namespace name
syntax error : identifier 'Engine'
```

Clearly, I'm missing something important here. What am I doing wrong?

*note: I am aware that circular dependency is a bad thing, but in my particular case I believe that it is relevant.*

Comment: Your code compiles on MSVC 10 after the edit. It must be another error in another piece of code.

Comment: Indeed. I guess I didn't do the appropriate modification on my real code. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are the errors coming from `dxmanager.cpp` or from another compilation unit that includes `engine.h` and/or `dxmanager.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the forward-declaration of class `Engine` the namespace `XEngine` doesn't exist at this point.

A workaround would be moving the declaration inside the namespace block.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Still 10 errors left though.. =/ The same type of errors.

Answer (score 3):

In DXManager.cpp you are not just using some names from namespace XEngine. You define the function in that namespace.

So must be:

**DXManager.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Engine.h"
#include "DXManager.h"

namespace XEngine {

void DXManager::run(Engine *engine)
{
    std::cout<<"DXManager::run"<<std::endl;
}

}
```

AFAIK some of the compilers (like MSVC) process `using` variant too.
  But it is not correct because your syntax tries to define function `::DXManager::run` - not `::XEngine::DXManager::run` you intend to define.

Comment: I'm taking a mental note of this. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

When Engine.h includes DXManager.h, the latter defines a class XEngine::Engine without declaring the namespace first.

Comment: I moved the forward declaration within the namespace, but I'm still getting the errors though.